# How do I make the host work in UNet?

Tags: unity, networking, unity-networking

According to the "High Level API" [documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetManager.html), unless I misread something, a Host "just" runs both as a Server and as a Client, so much that it would require no special support, i.e. it should run out of the box.

When the Server and Client are in separate processes, both work correctly. When a host acts as both the server and client, this is not the case.

When `OnServerReady` gets called on the Host, the `NetworkConnection conn` parameter has `.hostId==-1`, and if I try to call on `NetworkServer.AddPlayerForConnection` I'll get [a warning and an error](http://pastebin.com/aeCsuXdt).

```
ClientScene::InternalAddPlayer: playerControllerId higher than expected: 0
UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkServer:AddPlayerForConnection(NetworkConnection, GameObject, Int16)
[...]

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
UnityEngine.Networking.ClientScene.InternalAddPlayer (UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkIdentity view, Int16 playerControllerId) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/Networking/Runtime/ClientScene.cs:90)
[...]
```

If I refrain from calling `AddPlayerForConnection`, then I'll encounter a warning (and no result) as soon as the Host calls a `Command`:

```
Trying to send command for non-local player.
UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkBehaviour:SendCommandInternal(NetworkWriter, Int32, String)
[...]
```

In fact, `isLocalPlayer` is `false`.

Am I doing something wrong, is the documentation wrong, or is this a bug?

---

As requested, some piece of code:

```
public override void OnServerReady (NetworkConnection conn)
{
    base.OnServerReady(conn);

    Transform spawnPoint = FindObjectOfType<SpawnPoints>().getNextSpawnLocation();

    GameObject controllerGO = instancedElements.SpawnObjectFree(playerPrefab,spawnPoint); // this is basically an Instantiate
    GameObject playerGO = instancedElements.SpawnObjectFree(playerCreaturePrefab,spawnPoint);
    [...]
    NetworkServer.AddPlayerForConnection(conn,controllerGO,0);
    NetworkServer.Spawn(playerGO);
    [...]
}
```

*(I've trimmed it down to remove the non-relevant parts)*

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to set up your Host and Client?

Comment: @JeremiahLeslie I've posted `OnServerReady`, the client does nothing special on setup, let me know if you need me to dig something else…

Answer (score 1):

In the `OnServerReady` callback the connectionID is passed as -1 to indicate a no connection between server to server. In the connectionID parameter you should pass the connection between the localClient and server using `NetworkServer.localConnections`. If localConnections return only -1, then it means that you are not connected as localClient. Refer unity docs and look for the word host

Comment: On `NetworkServer.localConnections` I have one connection, which in turn still has `.hostId==-1`.

Comment: That means you are not connecting to the server as localClient something like this here http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetClientServer.html

Comment: @user3506498 this is the correct answer, i recommend you supply this as an answer instead of a comment so you can be voted for the bounty.